# Error due to change in relationship

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am getting the following error message when I changed the relationship from `one-to-one` to `one-to-many` for following relationships

```
eventSch?.setValue(eventDesc, forKey: "eventDec")
eventDesc.setValue(eventSch, forKey: "eventSchedule")
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for
>   to-many relationship: property = "eventDec"; desired type = NSSet;
>   given type = EventDec; value =  (entity:
>   EventDec; id: 0x60800022bcc0
>    ;
>   data: {
>       eventSchedule = nil;
>       eventStatus = 0; }).'

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Did you make a new model version? If you are just in development you can simply delete and reinstall.

Comment: No, I did not make a new version. You mean delete model and reinstall?

Comment: Assuming `eventSchedule` and `eventDec` are inverse relationships, you do not need to set both.  It's easiest just to set the `to-one` end of the relationship (CoreData will automatically update the inverse), so just delete the first line.

Comment: @pbasdf, Actually your solution solved all my problems. Appreciate it a lot :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `eventSch?.setValue(eventDesc, forKey: "eventDec")` is causing errors, because you are supplying an entity; instead you should be supplying an NSSet.

I don't know Objective-C well; however, your code should look something similar to this:

```
NSMutableSet* eventDescSet = [NSMutableSet set];
[eventDescSet addObject: eventDesc];  // you have your set with one item
eventSch?.setValue(eventDescSet, forKey: "eventDec")
```

Also, I would use more descriptive names for clarity.

Comment: Appreciate your explanation, my code is in swift :)

Comment: Oh sorry about that :). Seing you are using KVO, I wrongly assumed it was Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

There is an SQL file on your device that is based on the old version, so when the app tries to load it based on the new model it can't figure out how to read it.

**[Hard solution]** If you have you app already published on the appstore then you should rollback your model to what it was at the time that you published, and then make a new model with your changes.

**[Easy solution]** If you are the only person with the app, and you are still in development there is no reason to make a model version.  Just delete form your phone (and/or the simulator) and reinstall.  The SQL file based on the old version will be gone.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into this problem as well apart from my above said problem